# Correcting database structure with MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a fairly straight forward database structure I would like to create with MongoDB. My structure looks like this:

```
    {url: value,
     users: {user_id: value}}
```

An example document might looks like this:

```
{'url': 'http://stackoverflow.com/', users: {'billy': 12, 'tommy': 2}}
```

I'm using PyMongo to update my database and add documents as show above. I can successfully add data to my database, but I cannot seem to duplicate the above data structure.

```
    for d in data:
        foo.update(
            {'id': d.get('url')}, 
            {'$addToSet' :{'users': {d.get('user'): 'NaN'}}},
            upsert=True)
```

The above code inserts but the 'user' structure is not what I intended. I would like:

```
users: {'billy': 'NaN', 'tommy': 'NaN'}
```

and I get:

```
users : [ { 'billy' : "NaN" }, { 'tommy' : "NaN" } ]
```

Can anyone help? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't get it. You get a nice list of user objects. Where is the problem with it?

Comment: `$addToSet` only works for arrays i.e. `list`s and not embedded documents i.e. `dict`s. To do what you want to do you have to write the python logic for since there is no update operation that could do the upsert using `$set`. Or, you could decide to make `users` into an array.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So what is best data structure for this data in Mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment above I would suggest not embedding a document but instead using an array. The following would work well:

```
{'url': 'http://stackoverflow.com/', 
 'users': [{'user': 'billy', 'value': 12},
           {'user': 'tommy', 'value': 2}}
```

This way you can leverage `$push`, `$pull` etc. as well as `$addToSet`. For the latter you could add a new user like this:

```
foo.update({'url': d.get('url')}, {'$addToSet': {'users': {'user': 'john', 'value': 0}}})
```

Now lets say you just wanted to increment a value for a given user, you could easily do that too:

```
foo.update({'url': d.get('url'), 'users.user': 'tommy'}, {'$inc': {'users.$.value': 1}})
```

To see more things that you could do with the schema I proposed I would read [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mongo very well but `$addToSet` suggest that there is a collection of users when instead it seems you need to add the key to users object instead.

I don't know if there is a mongo shortcut to this  in an upsert example

`foo['users']['billy'] = 'NaN'`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do. I also do not know Mongo to well, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.